# Return bit positions without loops

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

Is there any way of finding bit positions without using loops (for/while) in C++, using [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?
Suppose we have a binary number 11001 and we'd like to find all 0s positions.
Any sort of prebuilt, time-space efficient functions?

Comment: what do you mean? n-th bit is at position n, what do you want to "find" ?

Comment: Suppose I have number 11001 and I'd like to find all 0s positions

Comment: The keyword is "find" which requires "iteration" which requires looping

Comment: Given that there are no restrictions given on the size of the bitset, and therefore there is no specific limit on the number of 0 bits, it is logically impossible not to use loops in some form or fashion.

Comment: There's always recursion, but that would be the opposite of time-space efficient.  Gets rid of the loops though!

Comment: You can take a loot at the stuff in `<bit>` to see if there's anything that helps you for the operations you need.

Comment: why do you want to avoid loops? Often I have the feeling loops are tried to be avoided because loops cost time, though its the problem you want to solve that has a cost, the loop is just the way you arrive at a result. Avoiding the loop means to avoid solving the problem.

Comment: `we'd like to find all 0s positions` 0s are already there, _how_ do you want to "find" them? What do you mean by "find"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without using loops
>
> we have a binary number 11001 and we'd like to find all 0s positions

Unroll the loop yourself.

```
void check(unsigned pos, unsigned number, std::vector<unsigned>& out) {
    if (!(number & (1u << pos))) out.push_back(pos);
}
std::vector<unsigned> positions_of_0s(unsigned number) {
    std::vector<unsigned> ret;
    check(0, number, ret);
    check(1, number, ret);
    check(2, number, ret);
    check(3, number, ret);
    check(4, number, ret);
    return ret;
}
```